# Are US businesses paying historically low proportions of income as wages?

Tags: united-states, economics

In [this story about non-compete clauses for low wage jobs](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/10/15/upshot/when-the-guy-making-your-sandwich-has-a-noncompete-clause.html), the New York Times reported, "*American businesses are paying out a historically low proportion of their income in the form of wages and salaries.*"

Is this true?

Comment: While not an answer, the NY Times also published a [related article](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/04/05/business/economy/corporate-profits-grow-ever-larger-as-slice-of-economy-as-wages-slide.html) about 6 months ago. It compares both corporate *profit* and employee *compensation* against GDP, but in essence it says the same: businesses are making more while paying less.

Comment: @Geobits ah that's interesting.  I wish they had linked that from the article I was reading.

Comment: I think this is slightly misworded. **income** is a measure of money coming in (profit/loss ledger), while salary/wages are expenses going out. Wouldn't it make more sense to compare wages/salary to **total expenses**? For example, if a business's income remained flat, but non-wage costs increased (materials), you could get historically low wages as a percentage. Or if their wages stay flat or even increase, but companies are making record incomes you could get the same result.

Comment: I agree with @user1873 that "income vs. wages" (while echoing the text of the claim) is flawed. But in general, the broader point (profit rate increases vs. wage stagnation) seems so well established I wonder if I'm missing a subtle point about which you're skeptical? (Google "business profit versus wage graph")

Comment: @LarryOBrien, I can see that as a possibility, but does that mean they are measuring business profits before (taxes, depreciation, capital expenditures) versus wages. Or after those expenses.